# On irreducible algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

I have the following maybe trivial quesion regarding real algbraic sets:

Suppose $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an irreducible real algebraic variety (i.e. it can not be written as union of two algebric varieties) and let $W\subset V$ be an algebraic variety. Does $\dim W=\dim V$ imply $W=V$?

I know that this is true in for complex algebraic sets, but I also know that in real analytic setting many things can fail (hopefully not for algebraic).

I belive that the answer is positive but I've been looking at the literature Bochnak et al., Cox et al., and  Shafarevich and I couldn't  found a definitve answer. So if the ansewer is positve then please give hint of an argument, or else provide an counterexample. (Ps: I'm mostly interested in the case where $\dim X=1$).

Comment: I've upgraded your MathJax a bit: please use the supplied commands for operators (or `\operatorname` if needed) rather than the workaround you were using.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking just on the level of points, then yes, this is true. If an irreducible topological space $X$ is a closed subspace of an irreducible topological space $Y$ then the dimension of $Y$ must be at least the dimension of $X$, with equality iff $X=Y$: any chain of proper inclusions of closed irreducible subsets of $X$ is also a chain of proper inclusions of closed irreducible subsets of $Y$, and if $X$ is a proper closed subset of $Y$ then we can always extend any chain of proper closed subsets by plopping $Y$ on the end.

Comment: KReiser, thank you for the answer but i have troubles understanding your argument using chains of inclusions. Do you have any reference that i can look into?

Comment: This is just the definition of dimension. You can find some expository material about it at the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0055) or in most introductory books about algebraic geometry - for instance, Hartshorne defines dimension in chapter I section 1.